# How accurate are deportation policies depicted in the show?

Tags: realism, orange-is-the-new-black

In one of the episode from the last season of *Orange is the New Black*, a character was deported even though she didn't commit any crime (except entering the country illegally) and moreover has two children born in the US.

In the same episode, we also see small children being judged and deported. In another episode, one of the main characters was deported even though she never had been in the country of destination.

Is this true to reality or was this over-dramatized in the show? Can a parent of US born children be deported and can small children be deported like shown?

Comment: I rephrased the question a little, concentrating on what *actually* relates to the show more rather than generally discussing how deportation works. I also removed the really broad question about not getting noticed that seemed to have *zero* relation to the show. `realism` in all honours, but at some point this site stops to be a viable resource for all kinds of possible things being accidentally shown in an unrelated TV-show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be better served on Law.SE but...

> Can a parent of US born children be deported?

### Broadly, Yes

The child having US citizenship does not grant the parents permission to stay. If an alternative placement within the family, such as aunts, grandparents etc. (who **do** have permission to stay), it is quite common for the child to be placed there.

Appeal is possible (see more information [**here**](https://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/will-having-us-citizenship-children-prevent-deportation-undocumented-immigrant.html)) and a judge may override the wishes of ICE.

> Can small children can be deported?

### Again, yes

If they are not citizens (or their parents) then they do not have any legal right to remain and can be deported as recent events have shown.